# Best Way to Keep 2 Systems in Sync Via Webservice

Tags: web-services, api, synchronization

We have a system that allows users to submit forms to an agency. The client logs in, chooses a form, fills it out, then submits. Easy.
The form contains details such as addresses and parts which are added to the database so the user can maintain (create, update, delete) the address book or parts list and select them from drop downs in the form. That way they wouldn't have to retype everything each time they wanted to fill out a form (they fill out several each day).
The interface side has been working great for years but now we have a client who wants to automate things a bit and be able to create the forms via a webservice.
Implementing the add/update/delete is easy to do. The problem I'm having is on how to keep both systems in sync.

The client already has their addresses/parts lists on their own database. I was thinking that they would initially have to give us the data so we can verify the addresses/parts and add it to our database. So when they pass an address or part to us we would need to define the uniqueness based on a set of keys such as a combination of company, address, postal code, country for addresses and a set of keys such as part code, tariff, country for parts.
Using this key we would know whether or not this is a new address/part and add it to our database when they send us their form data via API.
What gets complicated is that if they happen to update a field on their end and send that via the "create form" API call, our end would detect it as a new address/part and create a new record because a field in the combined key would have changed. Over the course of time this can cause several duplicates with slight differences (note that each new address/part is flagged for staff verification). Once the form is created, they are able to view it in our system. But now if they wish to edit an address or part, because there are several "duplicates" they wouldn't know which is the "correct" address/part that they should be choosing.

My thinking was that we essentially want them to send us "correct" data and avoid duplication so when we do the initial mass verification/insert into our database we can return ID's (from our database records) so they can add an extra column in their table and associate our ID to their respective address/part. Any newly created parts on their end would make an API call to our system to create the same part in our database and return the ID so it can be associated. If a part is updated on their end, they would use the ID (our record ID) stored in their database and make an API call to update the associated record on our database. If they delete a part, they would make an API call to delete it on our end. To keep everything clean, when they make the "create form" API call and pass in the address/part detail, they would have to pass in the associated ID (from our database records stored on their end) because our form records store the associated address/part ids so in the "edit form" view, that record would be pre-selected in the drop down.

Are there better ways to do this? Before thinking of the API method as described above, I was thinking of having them pull data (list of addresses/parts) from our database via API call but there are several syncing issues that may occur. If they updated data on their end it would be overwritten by the data they pulled. Another issue is about how to defined uniqueness. Because there can be several parts with the same part code, same tariff, but maybe different country. Or a different combination such as same part code, same tariff, same country, but another field is different. So if they pass in an address or part via the "create form" API we would need to know whether it was a new one or it's just an update and it gets complicated with multiple keys and several combination so I figured ID's would be the best way to go (if we can get them to store our ID reference on their end that is...).

Would appreciate any insight on this and what the best implementation method would be.

Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts or suggestions? I'm going to have to implement this pretty soon so would appreciate any feedback before I go implement a solution.